# why <p:ajax> listener being called multiple times when it is used in a page which is included using <ui:include> in another page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, weblogic12c

I have a strange problem with placing `<p:ajax .../>` inside a page which is included in another page using `ui:include`. The problem is that the `listener` of the `<p:ajax listener="someMethod"/>` is being called more than one times in this situation!

For example I've created a composite component to render `list-of-value` component. It is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<composite:interface componentType="LovComponent">
    <composite:attribute name="actionListener" method-signature="void openModalDialog(java.lang.String)"/>
    <composite:attribute name="selectEventListener" method-signature="void selectAction(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent)"/>
    <composite:attribute name="id"/>
    <composite:attribute name="update"/>
    <composite:attribute name="value"/>
    <composite:attribute name="style"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
        <p:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.id}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" style="#{cc.attrs.style}"/>
        <p:commandButton immediate="true" process="@this"  icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#{cc.attrs.actionListener}">
            <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{cc.selectEventListener}" update="#{cc.attrs.update}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

And it works without any fault and render something like this:

[image]

And when the user clicks on the button it will show a list-of-value in a modal dialog. After that when the user select one of the values (He/She should click on that stupid refresh button!)

[image]

Then the dialog is getting closed and a select listener is being called in the backing bean to set the value in the correct bean (data holder bean).

```
<p:cellEditor>
      <f:facet name="output">
            <p:outputLabel id="casProfileAllowedCurrInfoGbiCurrencyCodeOut" value="#{casProfileAllowedCurrInfo.gbiCurrency.code}"/>
      </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="input">
            <g:Lov id="casProfileAllowedCurrInfoGbiCurrencyCodeIn" selectEventListener="#{accountProfileController.allowedCurrenciesPageFragmentCasProfileAllowedCurrInfoSelectAction}"
                                value="#{casProfileAllowedCurrInfo.gbiCurrency.code}"
                                update=":profileDetailform:allowedCurrenciesCasProfileAllowedCurrInfoDataTable"
                                actionListener="#{accountProfileController.openModalDialog('CurrencyLov')}"
                                style="width:98%"/>
      </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
```

The code for the select button (the button with refresh icon on it!) in the dialog:

```
<p:column headerText="#{label.SELECT}">
     <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-refresh" actionListener="#{currencyLovController.closeDialog(gbiCurrency)}" />
</p:column>
```

When this composition is used in a standalone page, the method for selectEventListener (custom attribute of the LOV composite) is being called once after the selection of the user is completed. (This is the desired behavior)

**Now my problem is:**

When I use it inside a page which is included in another page using `ui:include` the listener is being called two times! And bad news is the selected value is `null` in the second time! I couldn't find the relation between using this in an included page, But, I somehow sure it has a connection, because when I include it in a two level included page, it is being called three times and the selected value is `null` in second and the third times.

Any help would be appreciated.

**[Update]**

I package my subsystems as `weblogic` `shared-library` and I have a `MainWeb` application which is deployed as an application in weblogic.

I use `Weblogic 12c`, `JSF2.2 apache my-faces 2.2.7`, `primefaces 5.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem! It wasn't because of including `composites` inside each other. The problem is being raise by the way of deployment in `Weblogic`. It may sound a little strange but the problem disappeared when I stopped using Weblogic `Shared-Library` deployment.

I had managed to deploy each sub-system as a shared-library and to deploy a Main project for general purposes (User authentication, Security, Menu, page templates, navigation, ...) as a web-application which was dependent to shared-libraries (the packaged modular deployments).

When the above problem showed-up, I started to remove config-files (faces-config.xml, web.xml) from shared-libraries, but nothing could solve the problem.

Finally I changed the way of deployment, and left the shared-library deployment down for now. When I packaged the whole application as one deployment, the problem disappeared!

I couldn't find out what caused the problem, but now at-least it is working!

Hope it would be helpful for others.

Comment: Web fragment libraries belong in /WEB-INF/lib of WAR.

Comment: @BalusC:  I couldn't find out what does it mean? So you are saying if I put my web fragment files in /WEB-INF/lib, It would solve my problem even if I use `shared-library` deployment again?